# Significance of Publish().RefCount() in this example?

Tags: system.reactive

I am in the process of learning RX and have run across a sample on the Intro to Rx site that I have a question about. Here is the example which implements the same functionality as the Window with count extension method:

```
public static IObservable<IObservable<T>> MyWindow<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source, 
    int count)
{
    var shared = source.Publish().RefCount();
    var windowEdge = shared
        .Select((i, idx) => idx % count)
        .Where(mod => mod == 0)
        .Publish()
        .RefCount();
    return shared.Window(windowEdge, _ => windowEdge);
}
```

I understand the purpose of the `var shared = source.Publish().RefCount()` line to 'share' the source with the window edge query. What I don't understand is why the `windowEdge` query was also defined with the `.Publish().RefCount()`? Can someone please help me understand why this would be necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good Question!

### Long Answer

Aside from performance reasons, the reason windowEdge is ref-counted has to do with the use of `Select`.

In this example, `Select` is using the index argument (`idx`), who's value is determined uniquely for each new subscriber. Therefore, if we did not ref-count `windowEdge`, each new subscriber would receive an event upon the next item yielded, since `mod == 0` will always be true.

This means without ref-counting that each window would consist of exactly two values (assuming no other race conditions are introduced). Example:

When the first event fires, we create a new window and feed in the event, at which point we also use the window-closing selector to obtain an observable which will yield when the window should close. The next event fires, and is sent to the current window. That event also happens to be the first event that is sent to our window-closing observable (because `mod == 0` is always true). The window-closing observable has now fired, and the window is closed, leaving us with a window which contains exactly two elements. Repeat.

### TLDR

The use of ref-count for `windowEdge` is necessary to ensure we're only incrementing `idx` once per "MyWindow" observable.